# Understanding Multiplication of a Matrix with 1 (indicator function?)

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am reviewing a few machine learning papers that involve graphs. I am having a difficult time understanding what these papers mean by multiplying a matrix (C in the examples shown) by "1" (which I assume is the indicator function).

[image]
[image]

Is this "1" actually the indicator function or something else I'm completely unaware of? What do these statements mean (matrix multiplied by 1 equating 1).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the $1$ refers to a column vector with all entries equal to $1.$   They use a subscript $1_K$ or $1_N$ to say how many elements. The multiplication does say something about the possible arrangement of $0,1$ in the rectangular matrix

Comment: It looks like a vector of one's, e.g. $\mathbf 1_2=[1,\ 1]^{\mathsf T}$.

Comment: Thank you Will and Aaron. This makes sense :)